# Editing MessageKit layout

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, layout, messagekit

This is my first time using MessageKit. I am trying to customize my view but I can't find any helpful information on how to do so like setting insets and changing color of background.

[image: My current layout]

I want to start the view from below the title bar and change the background color and the background color of the messages.

```
func backgroundColor(for message: MessageType, at indexPath: IndexPath, in messagesCollectionView: MessagesCollectionView) -> UIColor {
        return isFromCurrentSender(message: message) ? UIColor.myGold : UIColor.headingGold
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to set `contentInset` for `messagesCollectionView` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` to start view below title bar

```
self.messagesCollectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: title bar height, left: 0, bottom: 70, right: 0)
```

To set background color of messages you have to use `MessagesDisplayDelegate` method and delegate, dataSource should be connected with view controller

```
func backgroundColor(for message: MessageType, at indexPath: IndexPath, in messagesCollectionView: MessagesCollectionView) -> UIColor {
        return isFromCurrentSender(message: message) ? UIColor.blue : UIColor.gray
    }
```

for more customization you have to check `MessageKit` example in `MessageKit` Repo

Comment: layout is working but message background color is not changing by using this function

Comment: `messagesCollectionView.messagesDisplayDelegate = self` add this line in your `viewDidLoad()` and check

Comment: Already added. Is there any tutorial for this because i am a beginner and can't understand from example project.

Comment: Sorry, i don't know if tutorial available or not, message background color working or not?

Comment: please add your code in your question for message background color

Comment: UIColor.myGold is color available or try to add just UIColor.blue for testing

Comment: Yes UIColor.myGold is the theme color I am using.